# Binding AAR doesn't include resource folder?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I have a problem on building a xamarin project by binding an AAR library.
The binding project has an AAR library which holds some resources there (Build Action : `LibraryProjectZip`).
The Android Application project in xamarin has the reference of that binding project.
Everything builds perfectly until some point...
When I run the application,at some point when the application needs to execute some code of that binding project (in this case, code from the AAR library), it will crash the application !
This error comes with the fact that the piece of code doesn't find a layout which is available in that AAR library...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/myapplication/android/R$layout;
at com.myapplication.android.view.MyView.<init>(NativeInAppView.java:27)
```

I checked the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/).

```
 LibraryProjectZip – Embeds an .AAR file into the resulting Bindings Library .DLL. This is similar to EmbeddedJar, except that you can access resources (as well as code) in the bound .AAR file. Use this option when you want to embed an .AAR into your Bindings Library.
```

So... This means that the resource should be included...
What is wrong with my project ?

Comment: Trivial question, but does it load the resource in a native Android project? I would double check also, strange pathnames (whitespaces/dashes)

Comment: @hichame.yessou Yes it does !

Comment: @Damiii : Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue trying to bind the android zoom sdk. The binding project works but the resources are not included. Any ideas?